# How to not escape backticks in comments

Tags: support, bug

I was trying to post a comment on escaping backslashes, and ran into some formatting issues.

Namely, how to *not* escape backtick characters, because by default, they are always escaped following a backslash, regardless of the number of backslashes.

(repro'd in comment below)

This is despite the fact that backticks are not escaped in this way in posts: `` `\` `` generates `\` as expected.

Backticks are tricky, so a workaround may be more useful than a fix. Unless, there are hideously more use cases than just regular expressions and questions about escaping strings?

Comment: `\` no code formatting, or backslash!

Comment: `\\` broken code formatting `<html>`

Comment: `\\\\` the last backtick always escapes `$oddities`

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Thanks - I had tried searching, but didn't come across anything. If anything, useful to know it's [status-bydesign]

Comment: Although, the answers to that question don't really show how to work around the issue.

Comment: actually one of them links to the meta.tex question with [this answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/503) but its fine that it's here too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double backticks.

```
``\``
```

Problem solved (try it in the comments below).

Comment: \`\`\\`\` gives ``\``

Comment: This doesn't give you extra whitespace, so I'll mark this is as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

To work around this issue in comments, put a space (or other character) between the backslash and the backtick, like so: ```\ ` ``

(to be repro'd in comment below).

Comment: `\ ` visible, code-formatted backslash

Comment: `\ ` working code formatting `<html>`