# How to fix, or document for users: Escaped backtick rendering, in question/answer or comment

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting

Noting this duplication of topic, I hope this question can also address, what else might be easily done?

This is a bug, or should be added to editing notes.

> Congratulations you discovered meta._.stackexchange.com and meta.stackexchange.com

is not a great help.

This is indeed a duplicate in trying to understand what's happening. About 40 (2/3rds of the 60 or so) [meta.se backslash backtick search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=50&q=backslash%20backtick) relate to this.

---

In the question & answer editor, the input:

```
`\``
```

produces the output:
```

Whereas in the comments, the same string correctly renders a code block containing a back-tick.

Comment: Copied & pasted from question/answer editor for comparison: In the question & answer editor, the input:
```
`\``
```
produces the output:
`\``

Comment: Duplicate of [How to not escape backticks in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190392/289905). Also described in [How do I format a backslash as code with backticks in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201663/289905) which also explains how backslashes can be escaped.

Comment: … although I may have misread your question. You expect `\`\\`\`` in posts to render as a code span containing only a backtick, correct?

Comment: I expect there to be one format for writing markdown, question/answer or comment (ignoring the multiline handling difference), and/or a note in the editing tutorial, or a prompt when a ``\``` is submitted in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best <strike>(only?)</strike>* way I've discovered to include a single backtick as a code span in posts is to use double ticks and spaces surrounding:

```
`` ` ``
```

Which results in: `` ` ``

I agree that it's unexpectedly inconsistent, however.

* As pointed out by [@hkotsubo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/401803/hkotsubo), `` <code>`</code> `` and `<code>&#x60;</code>` are also options.

Comment: You can also use `<code>\`</code>` or `<code>&#x60;</code>`

Comment: You're right! I missed those. I do like the terseness of the five backticks though.